# Login problem after migration from PHP 5.6 to 7.4 in Symfony application

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, symfony, ldap

A colleague of mine created a Symfony application some time ago using PHP 5.6 (an absence management system). On this application, there's a login system (which apparently looks in the MySQL database -> "user" table). The problem is that I have absolutely no idea how it works. The table is made up of these fields:

id,id_externalsoft,username,password,salt,roles(DC2Type:array),admin,adlogin,name,prename,mail,isrh,seeall,adlogin2,canaccess,MaTTT

So far, so good.

I decided to migrate my application to PHP 7.4 (because the old server is not maintained anymore). But I can't connect, except by entering the universal hard-coded password in the "user" table, which looks something like this: F98uJWPtWQaNc!@2UN&njK6orWLz#Ph@5cZsnM@yg?C@Pmk8kc...

The problem is that on the version on the old server with the old version of PHP, it works by entering the user's LDAP password, except that I see absolutely NO connection to LDAP in the code! I definitely don't know how it works. Can you PLEASE help?

I updated the project to Symfony 4 on the new server.

Here is my security.yml :

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
  encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    AbsenseBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

  providers:
    main:
      entity:
        class: AbsenseBundle:User
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      pattern: ^/
      anonymous: true
      provider: main
      form_login:
        login_path: login
        check_path: login_check
      logout:
        path: logout
        target: /login
      remember_me:
        secret: "%secret%"
        lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
        path: /
        # by default, the feature is enabled by checking a
        # checkbox in the login form (see below), uncomment the
        # following line to always enable it.
        #always_remember_me: true
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/calcul/evolution, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Here is my log file:

```
[2023-10-03 11:50:45] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader" instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader\" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use \"Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\DebugClassLoader\" instead. at C:\\wamp64\\apps\\absense\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader.php:16)"} []
[2023-10-03 11:50:45] request.INFO: Matched route "login_check". {"route":"login_check","route_parameters":{"_route":"login_check"},"request_uri":"https://xxx/absense/web/app_dev.php/login_check","method":"POST"} []
[2023-10-03 11:50:45] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Creating Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Creating Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0. at C:\\wamp64\\apps\\absense\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\UnderscoreNamingStrategy.php:66)"} []
[2023-10-03 11:50:45] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT u0_.id AS id_0, u0_.id_externalsoft AS id_externalsoft_1, u0_.username AS username_2, u0_.password AS password_3, u0_.salt AS salt_4, u0_.roles AS roles_5, u0_.admin AS admin_6, u0_.isrh AS isrh_7, u0_.seeall AS seeall_8, u0_.adlogin AS adlogin_9, u0_.adlogin2 AS adlogin2_10, u0_.name AS name_11, u0_.prename AS prename_12, u0_.mail AS mail_13, u0_.canaccess AS canaccess_14, u0_.MaPST AS MaPST_15 FROM user u0_ WHERE u0_.username = ? OR u0_.adlogin = ? OR u0_.adlogin2 = ? ["u125960","u125960","u125960"] []
[2023-10-03 11:50:45] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.notif_x_cases AS notif_x_cases_1, t0.email_x_cases AS email_x_cases_2, t0.notif_interview AS notif_interview_3, t0.email_interview AS email_interview_4, t0.notif_x_days AS notif_x_days_5, t0.email_x_days AS email_x_days_6, t0.notif_other AS notif_other_7, t0.email_other AS email_other_8, t0.email_x_retard AS email_x_retard_9, t0.notif_x_retard AS notif_x_retard_10, t0.user_id AS user_id_11 FROM user_settings t0 WHERE t0.user_id = ? [252] []
[2023-10-03 11:50:45] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at C:\\wamp64\\apps\\absense\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\UserAuthenticationProvider.php:86, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid. at C:\\wamp64\\apps\\absense\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:65)"} []
[2023-10-03 11:50:45] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"login"} []
[...]
```

I've tried changing the encryption method, checking the settings on my WampServer server, php.ini, and so on. Nothing works. I still get the "Bad credentials" error.

Comment: Did you try to create a user ? Cause I don't see any LDAP connection configured in Security.yaml

Answer (score 0):

### 1st idea

Replace:

```yaml
 providers:
    main:
      entity:
        class: AbsenseBundle:User
```

with:

```yaml
 providers:
    main:
      entity:
        class: AbsenseBundle\Entity\User
        property: email
```

I don't know If your `AbsenseBundle\Entity\User` class contains the `email` property, so please verify which property contains a unique value that is treated like a username.

### 2nd idea

Add the [LDAP User Provider](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/ldap.html#fetching-users-using-the-ldap-user-provider) to your `app/config/security.yml` configuration file.